# Why we cannot ascribe values to behavior of functions at poles?

Tags: complex-analysis

A long ago I have noticed that behavior of functions at poles can be described by what coefficient and power the term $\frac 1{x-x_0}$ needs to remove the pole. For instance, simple poles can be eliminated by adding the term just with a proper coefficient.

As such, an idea arized that we can give a name to the behavior of function $1/x$ at zero and then express the behavior of any function at any pole through it.

That is we postulate

$$\omega= \lim_{x\to0}\frac 1x$$

As such, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac ax=a\omega$ etc.

We can thus ascriobe $1/0$ itself the value of $\omega$ for continuity.

Omega defined this way would be quite unlike infinity: it would not produce indeterminate forms in similar cases, particularly,

$$\omega-\omega=0$$
$$0 \, \omega = 0$$

to measure the coefficient of omega we take the derivative of reciprocal function: $1/\left(\frac1{f(x)}\right)'=-\frac {f(x)^2}{f'(x)}$

Further we can ascribe values to a function at pole $x_0$ the following way:

$$f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} \left(\frac{f (x)^2 f''\left( x \right)}{2 f'\left(x\right)^2}-f (x)\right)+\omega \lim_{x\to x_0}\left(-\frac {f(x)^2}{f'(x)}\right)$$

or just generalize any funtion:

$$f^*(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)}2+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}2$$

Thus, we can obtain the following values

$$\cot 0 = \omega$$

$$\zeta(1)=\gamma+\omega$$

$$\Gamma(0)=-\gamma+\omega$$
$$\Gamma(-1)=\gamma-1-\omega$$
$$\Gamma(-2)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{\gamma }{2}+\frac\omega 2$$
$$\Gamma(-3)=\frac{\gamma }{6}-\frac{11}{36}-\frac\omega 6$$

etc.

I wonder what are the drawbacks in free use of such number.

Comment: What would the uses be? Note that there is also the concept of a **principal value** defined by
$$\text{p.v.} f(x_0) := \frac12 \lim_{h\searrow 0} f(x_0+h) + f(x_0-h)$$
Where $\text{p.v.} \frac1x = 0$ at $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: A one-sided limit. $\lim_{x\searrow x_0} := \lim_{x\to x_0, x>x_0}$

Comment: The [Cauchy principle value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) is what I have in mind, but this is actually an integral form of this.

Comment: @AlexR yes, this Caushy principal value is the real part of what I propose as a value of a function in a pole point. The other part is the same, but with another sign: $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}2$$ It will not be a real number (if the function has a pole in $x$, otherwise of the function is continuous it will be zero) but can be expressed in terms of $\omega$.

Comment: If one rewrites $(-2)! = (-1)!/(-1)$,  $(-3)! = (-1)!/(-1)/(-2)$, etc., and thus reduces the formal expressions of the factorials/gammas at the negative integers to the basis of the formal entity $\psi=(-1)!$ then the above regularizations  give easily expressions in terms of $\psi$ with the contents, that $\psi$ can be seen alternatively as multivalued form requiring $\gamma$ and the set of scaled Stirling-numbers first kind $s1_k \cdot 2! / k! $ which we can find by the generating function $\log(1+x)^2$ . *(I don't know/claim whether this adds anything useful to your observations)*

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand,
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac {dx} {x^2}= \left[ -\frac 1 x\right]_{0}^\infty = \omega,$$
On the other hand, by the transformation $x = 2y$, 
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac {dx} {x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^\infty\frac {dy}{y^2} = \frac{\omega}2.$$
That is $\omega = \omega/2$. Subtracting by $\omega/2$, and then multiplying by $2/\omega$, you obtain that
$1 = 0$, which could be considered a drawback.

Actually, $\omega = \infty$ in the extended complex plane, and in general neither subtraction by $\omega$ nor division of $\omega$ is well defined.

Comment: Good point. I will think about it.

Comment: Well. What do u think will happen if we postulate $a \omega =\omega$ but $\omega+a\ne \omega$, $\omega-\omega$ undefined?

Comment: Also for $a=0$?

Comment: I also think whether anythink will break if we remove infinity. That is, prohibit integration with limits at infinity (only allowing integration to $\omega$).